# using OBDII with can-utils Ubuntu

Tags: can-bus

i'm trying to figure out a way to communicate with my OBDII using can-util lib but i'm facing lots of issues my question is "is what i'm trying to do possible" if so why when i connect my OBDII the can0 interface doesn't show

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How are you trying to interrogate the system? How are you hooking things up (what connections on the OBDII port and what are you using on the computer itself)? Do you have a link to the utilities you're using? Do you get any comms out of the OBDII port? Can you give us more information?

Comment: the OBDII i'm using is a usb connection and so far i have Bluetooth , WiFi and another usb OBD's  in an attempt to connect it , the toutorail i'm trying to follow this tutorial https://bit.ly/2JGyvM7 . @PeterSmith